# Is there any way to save/favorite questions?

Tags: support, questions, watched-tags

For example, I saw [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/426/can-i-change-the-icon-for-a-game-in-the-windows-games-explorer) question, and I have the same question. I would like some way, within the system/site, to monitor this question if it receives an answer. I don't want to post a comment on it because I don't have anything additional/useful to add to it, but it seems that would be the only way to mark it to refer to later (through Activity). I am new to the stackexchange sites, so I'm not sure if there's some other commonly used method I just don't know about. If there's not, even something like the equivalent of Wikipedia's Watch option would be nice, or some other way to bookmark/favorite a question (which I imagine could be handy for Guide questions) so you can easily refer to it.

I realize I could just bookmark the specific page for the question, but as stated, I'd prefer an in-system way of monitoring stuff before cluttering up my bookmarks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Click on the star below the vote up and down arrows. A link to the question will be saved on the "favorites" tab on your profile page.

If you do this you'll get notified of any new answers or edits to the question.

Comment: Thank you very much! I feel kind of silly now. :P I'm glad to know this feature is there though and will be making lots of use of it. :)

Comment: Is there any way to view questions that you have marked as "favorite" directly? I.E., to return to a question you've favorited even if there have been no new updates?