# How would I track a (favorite) question?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any way to save/favorite questions?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92/is-there-any-way-to-save-favorite-questions)

Say, I need to track a question, in the sense that I want to be informed about every single change, the moment it is updated - most preferably by receiving a message which would display prominently on login/reload.

I can mark the question as favorite all right, but, is there a more "push"-esque way of achieving this?